# Application that doesn't stick to launcher in dash in Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome-shell, komodo, dash

I have installed Komodo Edit 7.0.2 and had to create a custom .desktop file in order to launch it from the Gnome Shell dash - see http://pastebin.com/VuKniTiM

Everything was working fine: one click on the launcher and its icon became "active", meaning that the application was now running, with the ability to switch between windows etc.

Since I accepted the auto-update to Komodo Edit 7.1 on July 17, my launcher still launches the app, but it sometimes doesn't become "active", and instead a new low-resolution icon of Komodo appears in the dash - the low-res icon in the dash lacks ability to add as a favorite or launch a new application window.

Do you have any idea how to fix that?
Where I should I have a look into?

Thanks in advance for you answers.

Comment: The wmclass thing seems to do the trick (I commented that specific line in my .desktop file). Any way I can give you credit for that?

Comment: I appreciate your thought. Maybe if the moderators migrate the question, I could answer it there, and you can vote/mark it. But anyways, for now, you can leave it as it is.